# ListView vs GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-gridview

Is there any performance advantage(s) for choosing listview over gridview column? Statically or dynamically gridview's column and/or row can be manipulated for different purposes.

Comment: You want a gridview with 1 column and 1 row?

Comment: My apology I have edited the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  ListView and GridView solve different problems.  ListView is a vertically scrolling collection of views with exactly 1 item per row.  GridView is a vertically scrolling collection of views with multiple views per row.

Comment: Does gridview memory-intensive than listview because of its multiple views per row?

Comment: Views on screen are simply views on screen.  The more views you have on screen, the more memory you will use.  The scrolling container wouldn't do much to change that.